# Why is my SQL request much slower when the condition is in the join?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have a table that contains the following columns:

1. ID
2. Master ID

The Master ID can be shared between different rows with different IDs.

E.g.:

```
ID | Master ID
1  |  1
2  |  1
3  |  1
4  |  2
```

Knowing the ID I want to retrieve all the rows that share the same master ID

I managed to do it using this query:

```
Select * 
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN table t2
ON t.MASTER_ID = t2.MASTER_ID 
Where t.ID = '1'
```

Then I also tried using:

```
Select * 
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN table t2
ON t.MASTER_ID = t2.MASTER_ID and t.ID = '1'
```

In that case, it was much slower. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Which dbms? (Different products optimize differently...)

Comment: Caching/disk issue? Compared execution plans?

Comment: Look at the query plan

Comment: Do they return exactly the same data set?

Comment: @JoePhilllips : the request is actually failing for the second one (I am using too much resources for that query...) but I got the explanation now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The queries are doing different things, the first you are saying:

```
1. give me all rows from `table` where `id = 1`
2. Also give me rows from t2 with a matching master ID
```

In the second you are saying

```
1. Give me all rows from `table`
2. Return rows from `t2` with a matching master ID and where `t1.ID = 1`
```

In a simple example you might have

```
ID  Master_ID
------------------------
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   2
```

So your first query will return:

```
t1.ID   t1.Master_ID    t2.ID   t2.Master_ID
--------------------------------------------
1           1           1       1
1           1           2       1
1           1           3       1
```

Your second query will return

```
t1.ID   t1.Master_ID    t2.ID   t2.Master_ID
--------------------------------------------
1           1           1       1
1           1           2       1
1           1           3       1
2           1           NULL    NULL
3           1           NULL    NULL
4           2           NULL    NULL
```

So basically in the first query you are returning a limited number of rows from your table, whereas in the second you return all rows, but only join to some of them.

Comment: Good catch :-). I assume this difference between `ON` and `WHERE` clause is only pronounced when there is an `OUTER` join. For `INNER` joins the predicates could be either `ON` or `WHERE`. Is that right? A sqlfiddle would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: That is correct, with an inner join both queries are equivalent. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bf52/1

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So basically the Where clause applies to the first table selected and not to the result of the join, right? I guess I missed this detail...

Comment: explanation on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause made it clearer!

Answer (score 2):

If the `t.ID = '1'` condition is in the WHERE clause the `t.ID='1'` condition only has to be evaluated for the number of rows in t. If the `t.ID='1'` condition is put into the ON clause for the join it must be evaluated for all rows in t2. If there are a lot of rows in t2 this can significantly increase the run time of the query.

Comment: Absolutely, but putting the condition in join on ... means the condition will be evaluated after joins matching operation. (or) before?

Comment: Having the condition in the ON clause for the join means the condition will be evaluated for each row in t2. It's evaluated to determine if the t2 row should be joined - so it's evaluated before the row is actually joined. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't include `t.ID = '1'` in `JOIN ON` condition since it's not the joined table. condition on the table in `FROM` part should stay in `WHERE` clause; whereas condition belongs to joined table should be moved to join on clause so to get a proper outer join effect rather a inner join effect.

Comment: But doesn't the Oracle optimizer detect that?

Comment: @jarlh, should be but what optimizer will choose to perform not sure. even if you try to do this same in SQL Server probably same feeling caan be seen. At least I have seen ... not sure whether optimizer will neutralize it or not.

Comment: good observation, but the ON clause is a valid syntax to 1) perform an outer join for ID=1 and 2) preserve all other IDs filled with NULLs for T2. The real reason NOT to use it is that the resulting performance is much worst than for two queries performing 1 and 2 separately.

Answer (score 0):

You **don't need an OUTER JOIN**. The reason is simple, your are joining the same table on the same column - there can't be a non-match!

The query to use is therefore

```
 Select * 
 FROM T
 INNER  JOIN T t2    
 ON T.MasterID = t2.MasterID 
 Where t.ID = 1
```